# Why do electrons on the surfaces of a lens focus photons instead of scattering them in all directions?

Tags: refraction

Compton tells us electrons on the surface of a lens should scatter photons, not focus them. Imagine a photon traveling from a pinpoint on the surface of a source object to a silicon atom on a lens surface, and being refracted from that atom to a pinpoint on the image of the source object on the eye's retina. Imagine a second photon following the same path from the source pinpoint to the same atom on the lens surface. What are the mechanics that cause that same atom to refract the second photon to the same pinpoint on the eye's retina?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two things going on

- Many (most?) bound electrons are not free to Compton scatter light of optical wavelengths.

  That is, bound electrons are limited to the energies or allowed orbitals, and if the Compton scattering energy is lower than the smallest step from a currently occupied orbital to a unoccupied one than Compton scattering simple can't happen.

  Even if there are orbitals accessible to Compton scattering of visible band light, the cross-section for such scattering will include only those angles that have the *right* energy transfers, and will therefore be much lower than the free Compton scattering cross-section.
- Diffraction is a coherent phenomena which involves the interactions of light with the electrons of many atoms taken together and is more clearly described classically. It result from the combination of the resonant delay of light propagation in the medium and Huygen's principle.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. McKee.  After your reply, I checked Wikipedia "Huygens-Fresnel Principle," and the diagram "Wave refraction in the manner of Huygens" is what I'd better go with.  Wiki "Photon," Para. "Photons in Matter," gets me into polaritons if I want to think in particles instead of waves, way over my head. Del